# constexpr тернарный оператор

Tags: c++, if, тернарный-оператор

Существует простой

```
if(condition){x}else{y}
```

, для которого есть укороченный вариант

```
(condition?x:y)
```

Также существует проверка времени компиляции

```
if constexpr(condition){x}else{y}
```

Есть ли укороченный аналог для него?

Comment: Тернарный оператор - вовсе не "укороченный вариант" `if`...

Comment: @Harry символов меньше, значит укороченный :) Различие не только в этом, конечно, но вопрос не об этом

Comment: За что минус вопросу?

Comment: Попробуйте на место `x` поставить например `return;` - сразу почувствуете разницу.

Comment: `# define U(C,X,Y) { if constexpr(C){X}else{Y}}`